# edit data from mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am working on a CMS and seem to be having issues currently with my edit code and I can't figure out what the problem is for the life of me, when I submit to edit, everything goes through as if the edit was successful, however nothing is ever changed or submitted to the database.

I have been trying many different things and nothing seems to make any difference, I am totally lost on this one.

**editarticle.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/news.php');
include_once('includes/functions.php');

$article = new Article;
$funct = new UserFunctions;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    $articles = $article->fetch_all();

    if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);

        if (empty($title) or empty($content)) {
            $error = 'All fields are required!';
            header('Location: index.php?p=editarticle');
        } else {
            global $pdo;

            $query = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE articles SET article_title = ?, article_content = ? WHERE article_id=?');
            $query->bindValue(1, $title);
            $query->bindValue(2, $content);
            $query->bindValue(3, $id);

            $query->execute();

            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }

    //check if an article is selected to be edited
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $id);
        $query->execute();

        $rows = $query->fetchAll();

        //get the article title and content to put in edit inputs
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $id = $row['article_id'];
            $title = $row['article_title'];
            $content = $funct->br2nl($row['article_content']);
        }
?>
<!-- POST -->
<div class="post">
    <div class="topwrap">
        <div class="userinfo pull-left">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="" />
                <div class="status green">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>

            <div class="icons">
                <img src="images/icon1.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon4.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon5.jpg" alt="" /><img src="images/icon6.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="posttext pull-left">
            <h2>Edit Article</h2>
            <!-- add Article form start !-->
            <form action="editarticle.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
                <textarea rows="10" cols="87" name="content" /><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
                <!-- add article form break !-->
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="postinfobot">

        <div class="dateposted pull-right">
                <!-- add article form continue !-->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
            </form>
            <!-- add article form end !-->
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POST -->
<?php
    } else {
?>
<!-- POST -->
<div class="post">
    <div class="topwrap">
        <div class="userinfo pull-left">

        </div>
        <div class="posttext pull-left">
            <h2>Select an Article to Edit</h2>
                    <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
                        <?php echo $article['article_id']; ?> - <a href="index.php?p=editarticle&id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>"><?php echo $article['article_title']; ?></a><br />
                    <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="postinfobot">
        <div class="dateposted pull-right"> </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- POST -->
<?php
    }
} else {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

**includes/news.php**

```
class Article {
    public function fetch_all() {
        global $pdo;
        $article_status = 1;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_status = ? ORDER BY article_timestamp DESC");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_status);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetchAll();
    }

    public function fetch_data($article_id) {
        global $pdo;
        $article_status = 1;

        $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id = ? AND article_status = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $article_id);
        $query->bindValue(2, $article_status);
        $query->execute();

        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

I am getting back into PHP for the first time in 10 years and have been doing a lot of C# development over the last 2 years. I am finding it very difficult to troubleshoot issues with PHP thus far, as I have gotten very little or no error messages to work with (not even in the error_log on my host).

**Any ideas why this isn't submitting the changes to the database?**

Comment: when you clicked the edit button, is the data displayed?

Comment: You're using `?p` but I don't see `$_GET['p']` anywhere.

Comment: What is the return value of `$query->execute();`

Comment: You should set your error mode to throw exceptions if you haven't already - `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the editarticle.php is included within an index.php, so the $_GET['p'] is done in the index.php (since all other pages and templates are included into the index).

Comment: @Darren I tried something like that before posting here, and it never returned any errors.

Comment: @Meta but did you run a `try {} catch(PDOException $e) {}` around the update block?

Comment: yes, but I can try again.

Comment: you can use this class https://github.com/anzawi/php-database-class

to use databases

Comment: @Darren I added a try catch again, and echo $e in the catch block, but I get Fatal error: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in /home2/indieral/public_html/admin/editarticle.php on line 24 now (with the added line you posted for ATTR_ERRMODE above the query).

Comment: @Meta You need to change the `$db` variable to your actual database handler variable which looks like it'd be `$pdo`. Also, you want to echo `$e->getMessage();`

Comment: @Darren Thanks for the tip, hopefully this will help me in the future for debugging and troubleshooting issues!

Comment: @Meta It sure will! Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is seting $id with get when loaded. But then again you are posting the data to self by creating a new instance of post this new post doesn't know anything about $id

So you need to explicitly pass $id (unless it is a session variable, where you can use $_session variable to retrieve it) as a hidden value in your form
try adding this to form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
```

Comment: if this works, I will feel really dumb, because I had already had this at one point and removed it thinking it wasn't needed if i could just set $id without needing a hidden input).

Comment: This worked, however I also needed to add $id = $_POST['id']; above where i set the new title. I feel so dumb for removing that and then forgetting about it.

Comment: ofcourse @Meta you need a post variable to retrieve it

Answer (score 1):

As @noob pointed out, yu need to pass the article id in the first form, because your `UPDATE` statement need it.

Therefore:

```
if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['id'])) {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
        $id= $_POST['id'];
```

And in your form:

```
<form action="editarticle.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /><br /><br />
                <textarea rows="10" cols="87" name="content" /><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
                <!-- add article form break !-->
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>                              
    <div class="postinfobot">

        <div class="dateposted pull-right">
                <!-- add article form continue !-->
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit Changes" />
            </form>
```